# DB2 Perfomance issues

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have two DB2 environments. One of it has a performance issue, but it has almost same configuration parameters. But the slower environment has not so much system buffer pools. Can it be the reason for the performance difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Please give us extra info.